# Remove duplicates in large amount mysql database by time different in xsecound

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-query-store

I have looked at the other question with a similar topic, but it does not solve the issue I am currently having following table.

```
action_table(actionid,cookieid,intime,page)
```

I have data like follows

```
235470 ,994341855.1473047915, 2016-09-05 07:01:57, index.aspx
235471, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:02:00, index.aspx
235472, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:02:02, index.aspx
235473, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:02:12, home.aspx
235474, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:04:12, index.aspx
```

user can unlimited time of refresh his page its should be a duplicate like follows so only the auto increment (`actionid`) and the `intime`  only different so I just want get data like follows

```
235470 ,994341855.1473047915, 2016-09-05 07:01:57, index.aspx
235473, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:02:12, home.aspx
235474, 994341855.1473047915,  2016-09-05 07:04:12, index.aspx
```

avoid duplicate entry like cookie id and page is same and also if there is any page in between the same page then it should be a new entry.

How is possible to select like that query? Is there is any grouping is available?
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema

```
create table action_table
(   actionid int not null,
    cookieid decimal(20,10) not null,
    intime datetime not null,
    page varchar(100) not null
)charset=utf8 engine=InnoDB;

insert action_table values
(235470 ,994341855.1473047915, '2016-09-05 07:01:57', 'index.aspx'),
(235471, 994341855.1473047915, '2016-09-05 07:02:00', 'index.aspx'),
(235472, 994341855.1473047915, '2016-09-05 07:02:02', 'index.aspx'),
(235473, 994341855.1473047915, '2016-09-05 07:02:12', 'home.aspx'),
(235474, 994341855.1473047915, '2016-09-05 07:04:12', 'index.aspx');
```

Query

```
select actionid,cookieid,intime,page 
from  
(   select actionid,cookieid,intime,page, 
    @num := if(@page = page, 2, 1) as thePage, 
    @page := `page` as dummy 
    from action_table 
    cross join (select @page:='',@num:=0) xParams 
    order by actionid,cookieid,intime,page 
) as x  
where x.thePage=1 
order by actionid,cookieid,intime,page; 
+----------+----------------------+---------------------+------------+
| actionid | cookieid             | intime              | page       |
+----------+----------------------+---------------------+------------+
|   235470 | 994341855.1473047915 | 2016-09-05 07:01:57 | index.aspx |
|   235473 | 994341855.1473047915 | 2016-09-05 07:02:12 | home.aspx  |
|   235474 | 994341855.1473047915 | 2016-09-05 07:04:12 | index.aspx |
+----------+----------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Uses MySQL variables with a derived table `x` where if variable `@num` is 1 we will pick it up for the final output.

The `cross join` is merely for initializing the variables at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the analytical LEAD function in Oracle:

```
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT 235470 AS actionid, 994341855.1473047915 AS cookieid, TO_DATE('2016-09-05 07:01:57', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') AS intime, 'index.aspx' AS page  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 235471 AS actionid, 994341855.1473047915 AS cookieid, TO_DATE('2016-09-05 07:02:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') AS intime, 'index.aspx' AS page  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 235472 AS actionid, 994341855.1473047915 AS cookieid, TO_DATE('2016-09-05 07:02:02', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') AS intime, 'index.aspx' AS page  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 235473 AS actionid, 994341855.1473047915 AS cookieid, TO_DATE('2016-09-05 07:02:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') AS intime, 'home.aspx' AS page  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 235474 AS actionid, 994341855.1473047915 AS cookieid, TO_DATE('2016-09-05 07:04:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') AS intime, 'index.aspx' AS page  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT MIN(actionid) AS action_id, cookieid, MIN(intime) AS intime, page
FROM (
  SELECT input_data.*, LEAD(page, 1) OVER (ORDER BY intime) AS next_page 
  FROM input_data
)
WHERE page <> NVL(next_page, 'NULL')
GROUP BY cookieid, page, next_page
ORDER BY MIN(actionid)
;
```

Output:

```
ACTION_ID  COOKIEID     INTIME            PAGE
235472     994341855.1  05/09/2016 07:02  index.aspx
235473     994341855.1  05/09/2016 07:02  home.aspx
235474     994341855.1  05/09/2016 07:04  index.aspx
```